# Add button to run an ajax action in sonata user list

Tags: ajax, symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata, sonata-user-bundle

I'd like to add a button in sonata user list. This button is supposed to run a custom controller in ajax mode.

How do I do that?

```
sonata-project/user-bundle               2.2.4   Symfony SonataUserBundle
sonata-project/admin-bundle              2.3.7   Symfony SonataAdminBundle
sonata-project/core-bundle               2.3.10  Symfony SonataCoreBundle
```

Answer (score -1):

You extend the template of your page and add javascript